# HTML Table: Two text sizes in a cell?

Tags: html

Is it possible to have 2 Text files in a HTML Table, in 2 rows, but the second text/row should be smaller text size?

So:

```
11:00
+0:15
```

+0.15 should be smaller

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS font-size property to do this

Example:

```html
<table>
        <tr style="font-size: 20px;">
            <td>bigger</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-size: 10px;">
            <td>
                smaller
            </td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <style>
      .larger {
         font-size: 16px;
      }
      .smaller {
         font-size: 12px;
      }
  </style>

  <table>
     <tr>
        <td class="larger">bigger</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="smaller">smaller</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

You can use style tag to apply css rules, from there you can modify the style you want to it be.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
   <tr style="font-size:30px;"> <td>bigger font</td> </tr>
        <tr style="font-size:20px;"> <td>smaller font</td> </tr>
</table>
```